# How to use Bootstrap in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am making a app in which I want to  show a web page which is made using bootstrap.Can anyone show me how to do it.
The app I am making is like an article app so I want to make more quickly so I use Bootstrap to write the long article.
Here is the screenshot of the design but it will make more mesh if i write in dart.

[image]

Comment: Post what you did so far in order to help you better

Comment: there is one library which is providing same result as bootstrap for flutter :- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

Flutter does not come with a `Bootstrap` library. You can't use an existing one too, as flutter use neither a webview nor native components for rendering.

If you miss something that is available in bootstrap, create it yourself for flutter.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is an untested idea and I am rather unexperienced with that. But maybe it can guide you in the right direction.

You might be able to use [`flutter-view`](https://docs.flutter-view.io/) to include the Bootstrap css. You might still have to rebuild the interactivity though.